# Will this adapter work on a desktop?

Tags: wireless-networking, bluetooth

Will this adapter work on a desktop: Intel Network 7260.HMWG WiFi Wireless-AC 7260 H/T Dual Band 2x2 AC+Bluetooth HMCPartner; Bluetooth half Size Module

I also forgot to mention I have windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but assuming this is `mini PCI-e` you will either require a `mini PCI-e` to `PCI-e` adapter, along with a spare `PCI-e` slot, or a `mini PCI-e` to `USB` adapter (Not recommended as you'll need to put it in an enclosure and source antennas and possibly driver issues).

The adapter you buy would ideally have antennas attached to the backplate, there are a number available on various online stores, simply search `mini pci-e to pci-e antenna`. (Similar to [this link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005Q751BA) - picture below as this may become out of date otherwise).

Drivers won't be a problem, they are available on Intel's website.

Personally, as you need to purchase additional components anyway, I'd purchase a `PCI` or `PCI-E` wireless adapter (Cards with bluetooth exist) and remove the extra layer of complication.

[image: Mini PCI-e to PCI-e adapter]